# How does sidekiq know when a batch has all its jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

```
batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
batch.description = "Batch description (this is optional)"
batch.on(:success, MyCallback, :to => user.email)
batch.jobs do
  rows.each { |row| RowWorker.perform_async(row) }
end

sleep(x_seconds)

batch.jobs do
  rows.each { |row| RowWorker.perform_async(row) }
end

puts "Just started Batch #{batch.bid}"
```

In the above code it could be possible that the callback is called before the next batch jobs are added..so is there a way to inform sidekiq pro to not call the callback as the jobs in the batch are yet to be added?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you cannot do that.  Once you have completed the first jobs block, you cannot safely add more jobs to the batch, except from within another job in that batch.